# Change the key of XYSeries at run time

Tags: java, jfreechart

I know that I can set the title of my graph at creation time:

```
 XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Random Data");
```

but what if in my code I wanted to change the title **"Random Data"** to something else at runtime? The full code is provided here: [JFreeChart: XY Series Demo 3](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartXYSeriesDemo3.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `XYSeries` is a `Series`, so you can use `setKey()` to change the name. Because the name is also the series key, the listening `XYSeriesCollection` may veto the change. One workaround is to remove the series, change the name, and restore the series to the dataset:

```
private XYSeriesCollection dataset;
private XYSeries series;
...
dataset.removeSeries(series);
series.setKey("Stochastic Data");
dataset.addSeries(series);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`XYSeries` inherits from `ApplicationFrame` which inherits from `JFrame` which inherits from `Frame`; `Frame` has a `setTitle(String title)` method.

http://www.jfree.org/jcommon/api/org/jfree/ui/ApplicationFrame.html

Comment: +1 because I too often forget to update the title when I update the chart.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass series title via constructor param. You just have to modify code:

```
public XYSeriesDemo3(final String title, String mySeriesTitle) {
        super(title);
        IntervalXYDataset dataset = createDataset(mySeriesTitle);
        ...
}

private IntervalXYDataset createDataset(String mySeriesTitle) {
        final XYSeries series = new XYSeries(mySeriesTitle);
        ...
}
```

Then in your main method:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
        XYSeriesDemo3 demo = new XYSeriesDemo3("XY Series Demo 3", "my series A");
        demo.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
        demo.setVisible(true);

        demo = new XYSeriesDemo3("XY Series Demo 3", "my series B");
        demo.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
        demo.setVisible(true);

    }
```

Comment: passing via constructor is exactly what i dont want. I wanna be able to change it any time

Comment: Then you have to add set method and repaint call after its changed

Comment: how, that was my question in fact